# Use Javascript object from C# model to allow conditional display of MVC Razor elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP.net MVC App (using Razor views) I have a "ProductDetails" view.
This retrieves a "Product" model from the database.

The Product object, has a collection of "ProductVariation" (size, price, inStock etc...)

Something like this:

```
public class Product()
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public str Name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<ProductVariation> Variations { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariation
{
  public int VariationID {get;set;}
  public bool ProductID {get;set;}
  public bool InStock {get;set;}
  public double Price {get;set;}
}
```

(Obviously this is a very cut down model)

On my ProductDetails view, I have a dropdown to be able to select a variation.

What I want to be able to do is show / hide elements based on the selection.

Currently, I've got the price updating etc.. using jQuery.
I do this by creating a series of  tags with an id such as "1234-price"
(1234 representing the VariationID)

The value of my select element is the VariationID
So, i basically use a jQuery selector to get the value of the ID i want to show, and hide all the others.
This is working fine.

However, if a product is not available (ie InStock is false) I want to hide the "buy" button, and display some out of stock text.

How can I go about doing something like this?

Should I create an array of Javascript "product" objects on the page, from the model returned by my controller?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're describing, using a templating system, such as this: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

First, you would make a javascript object that reflects your database model. For example.... (ideally, this would be automatically generated with something like:

```
<script>
  var viewModel = @Html.Raw(JsonNetConverter.Serialize(Model))
</script>
```

However you go about generating that, you should end up with something like this:

```
var viewModel = { VariationID: 1, ProductID: 1, InStock: true, Price: 9.99 };
```

In your dropdown menu where users can select product variations, you would do something like this:

```
<select name="ProductVariations">
    <option value="1">Variation 1</option>
    <option value="2">Variation 2</option>
</select>
```

You would then need to make an action in your controller, like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetVariationById(int id)
{
    var model = new VariationModel();
    var variation = model.getVariationById(id);
    return View(variation);
}
```

Finally, you re-render your template with the new data you got back from your model:

```
$("#view-template").tmpl(viewModel).appendTo("#selector");
```